# TFTP Connect Request Failed

Tags: tftp

I am trying to setup a TFTP server on Windows Server 2012R2 for a university project, and I am running into an issue when trying to GET or PUT anything on the server.

The command `tftp -i 192.168.2.10 put C:\test.txt` on the server itself results in

`Error on server : ???????????????????? .
                                            Connect request failed`

I've made sure both ports UDP 69 and TCP 8099 are open on both inbound and outbound, and I've confirmed that the correct path for the test file is entered, because inserting a typo results in a `can't read from local file` error.

The `ReadFilter` value in regedit path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WDSServer\Providers\WDSTFTP is set to `\*` and the `RootFolder` value is set to `C:\TFTP` which does exist on the server.